# Computer suddenly shut down and won't restart

Tags: boot, crash

So I've been trying to fix this for a week now and I'm running out of ideas. My computer shut down while gaming (not crashed but seriously shut down) and then tried to restart. Right after POST when the boot screen appears (with the little turning dotted circle) it freezes after a second and then restarts again. I tried numerous times but I wasn't able to boot a single time after that crash. Chronological list of things I tried:

- interchanged PSU with spare
- put SSD into other PC (runs perfectly fine in other PC so it isn't an OS issue)
- interchanged GPU with spare
- bought new mainboard and installed it
- booting with a recovery CD resulted in the same crash on boot
- tried to boot with a Linux live USB, didn't work but I now have an error message:

  > mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 4: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: bca0000000000108
  > mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR 1ffffa9cf213c MISC d012000100000000 SYND 4d000000 IPID 500b000000000
  > mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:070f10 TIME 1686020064 SOCKET 0 APIC a microcode 8701013
- I have yet to figure out exactly what it means
- memtest86 resulted in no errors

This is my system: Ryzen 5 3600, Be Quite Straight Power 11 650W, B450 Tomahawk Max, Trident Z 16gb, Geforce GTX 1070.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems the only thing you haven't "replaced" is RAM and CPU - the error message suggests CPU

Comment: Jup, checked RAM and it still occured, ordering a new CPU right now.